# CSS doesn't work only inside Facebook canvas

Tags: css, facebook, heroku, laravel

I've created a Facebook application in Laravel 4 (hosted on Heroku platform).

On my local computer everything works fine. When I open the URL of the application directly on Heroku domain, everything works fine. But when I open it inside Facebook Canvas, CSS doesn't work.

Elements on the page, when inspected with Firebug, don't show any CSS, like it doesn't exist. But when I go to the option "View Frame Source" to view the iFrame code, CSS looks like it is loaded correctly?? CSS file is in public/css folder.

Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with embedding the font from Google Web Fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Because the prefix 'http' Facebook Canvas see this as insecure source. I just removed 'http'.